# GDCM can't load my DICOM file

Tags: dicom, gdcm

I have a Dicom file which is run perfectly on another DICOM viewer tools. But I can't seem open it with my GDCM viewer.

Here is the link for my DCM file
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwsYpl75gMyEbi1BNW52QmVtLWs

Can someone help me on why i can't open that DICOM file with my new viewer?

Comment: It's a Structured Report.  There isn't great support for SR in many viewers.

Comment: What problem exactly do you have?

Comment: gdcmviewer is meant to display a DICOM that contains an image (no PDF, no WAV, no SR, no TEXT, no XML...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a DICOM Comprehensive SR (Structured Reporting) document and no DICOM image. One reason why you can't display it with your DICOM viewer might be that SR documents (or this particular SOP class) are not supported, as "whiskeyspider" wrote. Another reason might be that the SR document is invalid (does not conform to the requirements of the DICOM standard). One problem is that the Date (0040,A121) value in Content Item 1.3.1 is empty:

```
D: $dcmtk: dsrdump v3.6.1 DEV $
D: 
[...]
W: Date (0040,a121) empty in content item (type 1)
W: Reading invalid/incomplete content item DATE "1.3.1"
E: Reading content item DATE "1.3.1" (Invalid Value)
D: ------------------------------- DICOM DATA SET -------------------------------
D: (fffe,e000) na (Item with explicit length #=4)          #  98, 1 Item
D:   (0040,a010) CS [CONTAINS]                               #   8, 1 RelationshipType
D:   (0040,a040) CS [DATE]                                   #   4, 1 ValueType
D:   (0040,a043) SQ (Sequence with explicit length #=1)      #  54, 1 ConceptNameCodeSequence
D:     (fffe,e000) na (Item with explicit length #=3)          #  46, 1 Item
D:       (0008,0100) SH [11779-6]                                #   8, 1 CodeValue
D:       (0008,0102) SH [LN]                                     #   2, 1 CodingSchemeDesignator
D:       (0008,0104) LO [EDD from LMP]                           #  12, 1 CodeMeaning
D:     (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem for re-encoding)   #   0, 0 ItemDelimitationItem
D:   (fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem for re-encod.) #   0, 0 SequenceDelimitationItem
D:   (0040,a121) DA (no value available)                     #   0, 0 Date
D: (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem for re-encoding)   #   0, 0 ItemDelimitationItem
D: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E: Reading content item CONTAINER "1.3" (Invalid Value)
```

If you are interested in the contents of the SR document, you might want to give the DCMTK SR tools a try: http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/mod_dcmsr.html#Tools